# MimeTypeMap....getMimeTypeFromExtension() не работает под Robolectric

Tags: android, android-testing, robolectric

Вот такой вот простейший тест не работает под `Robolectric`: `getMimeTypeFromExtension()` возвращает `null`. Как следствие вообще весь код, который использует этот класс, тестить становится неудобно.

Как чинить?

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class,
        sdk = intArrayOf(21),
        manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
        application = RobolectricMdiaLibApplication::class,
        packageName = "ru.secret.id")

class FooBarTest {
    @Test
    fun MimeType() {
        val type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf")
        assertEquals("application/pdf", type)
    }
}
```